# Java returning generic type that extends an interface

Tags: java

I'm having this issue:

```
public interface Node {
    public<T extends Node> T copy();
}

public class Point2D implements Node {
    @Override
    public <T extends Node> Point2D copy() {
        return new Point2D(this);
    }
}
```

Why do I get `The return type is incompatible with Node.copy()` ? Point2D implements Node, how can I make the error dissapear keeping the returned type?
If I put T instead if Point2D copy() I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Point2D to T" which is stupid because T is defined as a class that extends Point2D

Thanks

Comment: A generic method is parameterised when it is *called*.  What you're trying to do doesn't make sense (consider code like this: `Node node = new Point2D(); Foo something = copy();  // attempts to call "T copy()" with T==Foo`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `<T extends Node>` declaration for `T` in child class.
Use simply

```
public class Point2D implements Node {
    @Override
    public Point2D copy() {
        return new Point2D(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous, though:  http://ideone.com/8kCKvX.  The [CRTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165613/java-generic-type) is probably what's required here.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You try to cast `Point2D` to `Point3D`. It's two different implementation, you cann't do it.

Comment: @Ilya: I don't cast anything.  But that's exactly the problem, this code isn't type-safe.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth what do you expect in your code? `Point2D` returns `Point2D` instance, it cann't use it as `Point3D`

Comment: @Ilya: What I'd expect is the compiler to catch this if I try to do something silly.  But your suggestion doesn't allow the compiler to catch it.  The CRTP *does* allow it to be caught.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ok, I understand. CRTP is a better way here

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use type variables in this case. Java allows you to specialize the return type in overridden methods. That is, the following works:

```
public interface Node {
    public Node copy();
}

public class Point2D implements Node {
    @Override
    public Point2D copy() {
        return new Point2D(this);
    } 
}
```

The reason that this works, is that the `Node` interface specifies that the `copy()` method returns a `Node` instance. The class `Point2D`'s `copy()` method does return an instance of `Node`; in fact, it returns an instance of the subtype `Point2D`.

Comment: You're suggesting an identical solution to the existing answer.  But read the comments there for why this isn't great.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No, the solution is not identical, because also the `Node` interface has been changed: the return type of `copy()` here is `Node`, not `T`. The code on the website you link to doesn't compile, because you cannot (implicitly) cast from `Node` to `Point3D`.

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't noticed you changed the `Node` interface definition (if you make a dummy edit to your post, then I can remove the downvote).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth. No problem. Do you really need a dummy edit to remove your own votes?

Comment: Yeah, after 1 hour votes can't be retracted unless the answer is modified :(

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth. Okay, I didn't know that. Anyway, I've made a small edit.