# How to restrict generic type of interface to accept only implementor class

Tags: java, generics

My case is different but as an example

```
public interface Comparable<T>
```

would allow me to say:

```
public class MyType implements Comparable<OtherType>
```

but this is rarely what you want to achieve.

Is there a way to *force* me to say:

```
public class MyType implements Comparable<MyType>
```

---

The closest I got is:

```
public interface Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

This only works partially, as it won't allow `OtherType` if it's not comparable itself, but would allow:

```
public class MyType implements Comparable<Integer>
```

as it meets the conditions.

Comment: Can't be done in Java. At least not at compile time.

Comment: Maybe if you say why do you need such a restriction enforced at compile time we can come up with different design. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @SergGr Simply to reduce a check at runtime. The default method of that interface does a whole annotation processing, and strictly requires them to be of same type (or at-least a sub-type).

Comment: And why that interface has to be generic at all? Does it have some input or output params of the generic type? Can't it use just `this.getClass()` in the code?

Comment: @SergGr more precisely, I'm defining an interface `Copyable<T>` with method `default void copyFrom(T other)` and scan field after field for the `@CopyField` annotation... Etc.

Comment: And reflectively sets all these fields in `this` equals to its corresponding field in `other`.

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165613/java-generic-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Java.

Consider if it were possible to require that the type argument of `Comparable` be the same as the implementing class. Then if you had a `class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>`, and then also a `class Bar extends Foo`, `Bar` would also automatically implement `Comparable<Foo>` by the way that inheritance in Java works. But that would violate the constraint that the implementing class is the same as the type argument, as `Bar` does not implement `Comparable<Bar>` (and you can't even explicitly have `Bar` implement `Comparable<Bar>`, as a class cannot implement a generic type with two different type arguments).