# Is it OK that parent class know the type of derived classes?

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns, software-design

Is it ok that parent class knows the type of it's derived classes via a generic parameter?

```
class Cloneable<T> where T : is Cloneable {
    abstract T clone();
}

class A : Cloneable<A> {
    override A Clone() {
         // The child class knows how to clone itself.
         return new Child(...);  
    }
}
```

In the base class (*Cloneable*), I have an abstract method (*Clone*) that should be implemented in derived classes.
I want that the **return type** of *Clone()* method in the base class be a derived class (*A*).

Does this pattern violate any software design principle?
Do you know any similar design in .Net class Library or Java?

Comment: This pattern is known as Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. Legit pattern for the most part, except that it has a weird loophole `class EvilClass : Cloneable<A> {...` Unfortunately most type systems (Java included) cannot enforce `where T : this`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165613/java-generic-type)

Comment: Interesting - all you need to do is change the constraint to: where T : Cloneable<T>. I don't understand the reason for closing the question.

Comment: I think no, it does not and I think the similar design pattern is: https://www.oodesign.com/prototype-pattern.html