# Cloning object of subclass type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I wanted to be able to define a method to clone an object that is the same type of itself. I define the interface requesting such, but the following does not compile or run.

```
interface Foo {
  fun <T: Foo> copy() : T
}

class Bar(private val v:Int) : Foo {
  override fun copy():Bar = Bar(v)
}

main() {
  val bar1 = Bar(1)
  val bar2 = bar1.copy()
}
```

If however I write the implementing class in Java, it will compile

```
class Bar implements Foo {
  private int v;
  public Bar(int v) {this.v = v;}

  public Bar copy() {
    return new Bar(v);
  }
}
```

I can rewrite the code like the following that compiles:

```
interface Foo<out Foo>{
  fun copy(): Foo
}

class Bar(private val v:Int) : Foo<Bar> {
  override fun copy(): Bar =  Bar(v)
}
```

However the following will fail with error: no type arguments expected for fun copy(): Foo
val newF = f.copy()

```
fun <T: Foo> addFoo(
    foo: T,
    fooList: List<T>,
): MutableList<T> {
  val result: MutableList<T> = arrayListOf()

  for (f in fooList) {
    val newF = f.copy<T>()
    result.add(newF)
  }
  result.add(foo)
  return result
}
```

Is there a good solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Foo` doesn't know the exact type of the implementing class, so has no way to specify that its method returns that same type.

Unfortunately, Kotlin doesn't have self types (see [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371)), as they would handle this situation perfectly.

However, you can get close enough by using what C++ calls [the curiously-recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). In Kotlin ([and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2165660/10134209)) you do this by defining `Foo` with a type parameter explicitly extending itself (including its own type parameter):

```
interface Foo<T : Foo<T>> {
    fun copy(): T
}
```

Then the implementing class can specify itself as the type argument:

```
class Bar(private val v: Int) : Foo<Bar> {
    override fun copy(): Bar = Bar(v)
}
```

And because `T` is now the correct type, everything else works out. (In fact, the `: Bar` is redundant there, because it already knows what the type must be.)

Your `addFoo()` method will then compile with only a couple of changes: give it the same type parameter `<T: Foo<T>>`, and remove the (now wrong, but unnecessary) type parameter when calling `f.copy()`. A quick test suggests it does exactly what you want (creates a list with clones of `fooList` followed by `foo`).

Since it's often useful for a superclass or interface to refer to the implementing class, this pattern crops up quite often.

BTW, your code is easier to test if `Bar` has its own `toString()` implementation, as you can then simply print the returned list. You could make it a `data class`, or you could write your own, e.g.:

```
    override fun toString() = "Bar($v)"
```